# Avoid overlapping modifiers for hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Use case: my laptop keyboard (a Qwerty one with Azerty stickers on it) is missing the « `<` and `>` » key, which I absolutely need. Therefore I'm writing an AutoHotKey script to be able to type these characters.

Expected behavior: inputting « Left Ctrl + W » should programmatically type "<", and inputting « Left Ctrl + Left Shift + W » should programmatically type "<".

Issue: with the following script, inputting « Left Ctrl + W » programmatically type "<>", so the hotkeys seem to be overlapping… but I thought AutoHotKey was expected to not trigger a hotkey when extra modifiers are inputted.

```
; Left Ctrl + W
<^w::
SendInput <

; Left Ctrl + Left Shift + W
<^<+w::
SendInput >
```

However, the following script works as expected. I just added a "Return":

```
; Left Ctrl + W
<^w::
SendInput <
Return

; Left Ctrl + Left Shift + W
<^<+w::
SendInput >
```

Question: is it normal that AutoHotKey inputs "<>" with my first script? Is adding such "Return" the required syntax indeed, even though the script consists of just these 2 hotkeys?

Comment: See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro

Comment: Right, I think I got a bit confused by AHK [threads](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Threads.htm), and how to deal with them using [Return](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm) (in this case equivalent to [Exit](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Exit.htm)), which is somehow different from other languages. I wanted to make sure to really understand the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.

Either write the hotkeys on a `single line`, otherwise use `return`.

Valid syntaxes:

```
; Left Ctrl + W
<^w::SendInput <

; Left Ctrl + Left Shift + W
<^<+w::SendInput >
```

or

```
; Left Ctrl + W
<^w::
SendInput <
return
        
; Left Ctrl + Left Shift + W
<^<+w::
SendInput >
return
```